# Powershell Function runs for each item in array (I don't want this to happen)

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have created a script to provision Lync users, important details (such as assigned LineURI) for new provisions need to be emailed. Also any errors need to be sent (fluffed up with some friendly error messages of course :)).

So I created a few CSVs with all relevant data..

Then I created a function:

```
Function Send-Email ($attachArray) {
    # Get a list of to addresses
    $toAddresses = "foo@corp.local","bar@corp.local"

    # Process replacments
    Replace-EmailMasks

    # Send conditionaly
    Switch ($attachArray) {
        $null {
            Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "internalrelay.corp.local" `
                -From "test@andylab.local" -To $toAddresses `
                -Subject "There should really be something more informative here" `
                -BodyAsHTML $SCRIPT:htmlBody
            }

        Default {
            Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "internalrelay.corp.local" `
                -From "test@andylab.local" -To $toAddresses `
                -Subject "There should really be something more informative here" `
                -BodyAsHTML $SCRIPT:htmlBody
                -Attachments $attachArray
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I invoke it:

```
# Logic, then send
If (($npSuccess -gt 0) -AND ($errorsExist -gt 0)) {
    # Attaching both
        # Heres the summary paragraph
        $SCRIPT:customSummary = '<p>Success and errors :|</p>'
        # Now I'm sending it.
        Send-Email "$($tempPlace.fullname)\NewProviSsion_Output.csv","$($tempPlace.fullname)\Errors_Output.csv"
    } ElseIf ($npSuccess -gt 0) {..} # output-generating Success
        ElseIf ($errorsExist -gt 0) {..} # Failed somewhere
            Else {..} # no output-generating Success, no overall fails
```

Now this works; Email looks nice, goes to who it should, files attached etc..

**Problem** is:
For however many files I specify in *$attachArray*, that's how many emails get sent. The emails are all exactly the same, going to all the same people n many times.

It's as if i'm doing this:

```
ForEach ($item in $attachArray) {
    Send-Email "$($tempPlace.fullname)\NewProviSsion_Output.csv","$($tempPlace.fullname)\Errors_Output.csv"
}
```

Except i'm not..

To clarify my objective, I want the email to be sent to all in $toAddresses only **once**.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what's going on here?
Maybe I've just had a bad Monday morning..

Comment: Might be related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167580/email-with-multiple-attachments  Are you sure you attachment array is really an array?

Comment: From what I have read passing "string1","String2" makes it an array of strings. Maybe I should have used Param() in my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `switch` statement fires for each element of the array. This behavior is [documented](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847750) (check `Get-Help about_Switch`):

> If the test value is a collection, such as an array, each item in the collection is evaluated in the order in which it appears.

Use a regular conditional instead (since you have only 2 cases anyway):

```
if ($attachArray -eq $null) {
  Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "internalrelay.corp.local" `
    -From "test@andylab.local" -To $toAddresses `
    -Subject "There should really be something more informative here" `
    -BodyAsHTML $SCRIPT:htmlBody
} else {
  Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "internalrelay.corp.local" `
    -From "test@andylab.local" -To $toAddresses `
    -Subject "There should really be something more informative here" `
    -BodyAsHTML $SCRIPT:htmlBody
    -Attachments $attachArray
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ansgar Wiechers!, this worked, Do you know why the Switch statement behaves like this while If does not?

Comment: Because that's how `switch` is supposed to behave. Check the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @ansgar, so I could have used break in each action block. But as you said I only have 2 conditions.